# vb.net: index was out of range error

Tags: vb.net

can someone please help me. why does this return an error:

```
    Dim stuff As New System.Collections.ArrayList()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    Dim split As String() = temp_string.Split(",")
    For Each s As String In split
        If s.Trim() <> "" Then
            stuff(i) = s
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next s
```

the stuff(i)=2 line is returning the mentioned error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use stuff.Add(i) instead of that, you accessing not an array but a list which doesn't have an index upon creation only after you assign values you can access it's indexes as an array.

Comment: +1.  Deleted my own (incorrect) post and am throwing in my support for @eugeneK, who reads the question better than I do, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be an off by one error.  What is i initialized to?  0 or 1?